# call updated javascript function from different file

Tags: javascript

I have updated a function in a JavaScript file (index.js). index.js is automatically generated (every time I create a new panaorama scene). I'd like to be able to put the updated function in a new file (custom_functions.js) and add a line to index.html to include this .js.

```
<script src="js/data.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/index.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom_functions.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

my updated function is not being called (it's called from index.js) so I'm wondering if what I'm attempting to do is possible?

Comment: when you say updated function, do you re write it or what exactly ?

Comment: If your `index.js` uses a function from `custom_functions.js` then `custom_functions.js` needs to loaded before `index.js`

Comment: Your order of includes is fine. The function call inside custom_functions.js should invoke the function residing in index.js. It seems like the problem is not with inclusions. Is it possible that an error breaks the flow in the middle somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

When including external JavaScript files in HTML, the order of the files matters. If there are scripts that are dependencies of another file (IE they have variables/functions that are accessed elsewhere), they must be included first.

For example, if I have `a.js` and `b.js` as follows:

a.js

`b();`

b.js

```
function b() {
    return true;
}
```

Then the following will raise an error:

```
<script src="a.js"></script>
<script src="b.js"></script>
```

However, the following will not:

```
<script src="b.js"></script>
<script src="a.js"></script>
```

As suggested by Mortz, you should include `custom_functions.js` before `index.js` if `index.js` requires variables or functions defined in `custom_functions.js`.